# Trying to make flexbox tabbed content, and my tabs will not sit on top of the border from the content div below

Tags: html, css, tabs, flexbox, z-index

I'm trying to make the bottom of the active tab (class=windowTabs 'a' element) overlap the border of class=windowContent like shown in this photo, the bottom of Tab #1:

[image]

No matter what I do, I can't get it to go on TOP of the white border on class=windowContent

Take a look at my pen: http://codepen.io/agm1984/pen/vyRoYy

The problem is right here in the code:

> HTML

```
<div class="windowTabs">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openCity('London')">London</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openCity('Paris')">Paris</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openCity('Tokyo')">Tokyo</a>
</div>

<div id="London" class="windowContent">
  <h2>London</h2>
  <p>London is the capital of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="windowContent">
  <h2>Paris</h2>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="windowContent">
  <h2>Tokyo</h2>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

> CSS

```
 /* adamProperties Window Tabs */
.windowTabs {
  padding-top: 1.0em;
  flex: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 1.0em;
  min-height: 1.0em;
}
.windowTabs a {
  border-bottom: red;
}
.windowTabs a:after {
  border-bottom: medium solid black;
}
.windowTabs {
  margin: 10px;
  border-right: red;
}

/* adamProperties Window Content */
.windowContent {
  flex: 1;
  border-left: thin solid white;
  border-top: thin solid white;
  border-right: thin solid black;
  border-bottom: thin solid black;
}
```

If anyone ever searches this later from Google, just google the code from the city examples. You'll find the virgin example code.

I'm confused why I can't just put a 2px border on the bottom of the  element and make the z-index a larger number. According to my research, that should work when display: flex is on.

I also had a hard time trying to use to my advantage:

> CSS

```
.windowTabs a:after {
  any kind of shifting wasnt applying any change
}
```

I can see the div with the white border is on top of the buttons. How can I make it go below my `a' tags or how can I force something on top of them. I am trying to make it as responsive as possible, so I havent been looking too close at crazy methods of positioning, margins, absolute values. I feel like something simple is interrupting or missing, and probably related to flexbox.

Just to be super clear, here is a photo in which I am pointing to the problematic white border (I intentionally set the height on class=windowTabs to accentuate the issue):
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I've fully understood your question.  But I think a simple reason the window content div is not covering the tabs is because it has no background colour.

Try:

```
.windowContent {
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/LbmPjm

Apologies if I've misunderstood your question!

EDIT: updated codepen: http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/RoywKN

Comment: Good eye, but I don't quite think that is related. I added the background but it made me notice the border is there regardless, and the border is what I am trying to hide below the active tab. I changed the background colour of windowContent to red, and it went red, but when I change the background-color for windowTabs to red, nothing happens. TBH, I have to goto bed. I've been looking at this too long! nothing makes sense anymore.

Comment: Is it the reverse you want? Try adding the background-color to windowTabs a, and also add z-index to make it go on top.

Comment: Look at the first picture I posted, and compare it with the second one. See how the white border runs over top of the bottom of the tabs? That's the problem. I need to overlay the border below the tab with gray so it looks like the tab blends in with the content area below.

Comment: That doesnt work, or hasn't so far. Try it yourself in my codepen link.

Comment: Ok! I'll look again later :)

Comment: HOld on, I'm sorry. You're right. It's working with z-index:5; now. I could have swore it wasnt.

Comment: It might be some problem further up the DOM because I don't think it works in my real html file.

Comment: Ok, I've added codepen with background-color and z-index on the tabs, so you can play around with that

Comment: Ahhhhh, it was caused by missing background-color on the a tags! Thanks for your help. You made me see it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to pushes from ovokuro, I just solved it.

The actual problem was that I had no background colour on the buttons, so even though they were going on top, the border was still visible!!